# Unable to log in Dailymotion user using JS SDK

Tags: oauth-2.0, dailymotion-api

I have a React app from which I want to upload videos to the account of the logged in user. I have successfully done this retrieving tokens manually and calling the API but can't find a way to log in using the JS SDK in my React app.

I present the user with a button for log in:

```
    e.preventDefault()
    window.DM.login(
      function (response) {
        if (response.session) {
          // user successfully logged in
          console.log(response)
        } else {
          // user cancelled login
          console.log(response)
        }
      },
      {
        client_id: my_id,
        scope: "read write",
        response_type: "code"
      }
    )
   }
```

The login popup appears, I log in and get sent to the callback url. However, refreshing the original site, or the callback popup, still shows as no session and without login. I check with:

```
    status === 'ready' &&
      window.DM.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.session) {
          // logged in and connected user, someone you know
          console.log(response)
        } else {
          // no user session available, someone you dont know
          console.log(response)
        }
      })
  })
```

and I always get `{ status: "unknown", session: null }`

Loading the SDK is handled with a hook `const status = useScript('https://api.dmcdn.net/all.js')`

Do I need to handle something manually from the callback page? Isn't the SDK supposed to handle it in the background? I would appreciate some insights on what I might be doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, I spent hours trying to find a solution and, as soon as I post, I find it:

Client_id and response_type must not be passed in DM.login.

Instead, you have to pass the API key in DM.Init, like so:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    status === 'ready' &&
      window.DM.init({
        apiKey: '123456789',
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      });
  })
```

This brings up the popup and after inputting the credentials the SDK correctly detects the session, closing the popup and authing the user.